# How do I deal with pause/resume methods in pygame?

Tags: android, pygame, p4a

I hope I can to the right place.

I have produced a pygame app for android, however the p4a recipe does not include certain pygame-sdl methods such as APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND or APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND. When the app moves into the background (it continues to run, but the graphics freeze when brought forward). When I want to show ads, the app crashes. I understand how to use on_pause/on_resume methods with kivy, but I am using the pygame recipe. With pygame-sdl, I'd do something like this:

```
if pygame.APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND==TRUE:

   game_loop=False
  
elif pygame.APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND==TRUE:

   game_loop=True
```

However, is there another way I can do this without having to use pyjnius?
cheers,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've found the answer on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/jg5n6z/can_someone_please_help_problems_with_pauseresume/). I'm posting it here too, just in case someone else need it in the future.

It seems you can use the SDL2 constant values to check for them on Android:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == 259: # SDL_APP_APP_WILLENTERBACKGROUND 
        print('App about to enter background')
    if event.type == 260: # SDL_APP_DIDENTERBACKGROUND
        print('App entered background')
    if event.type == 261: # SDL_APP_WILLENTERFOREGROUND
        print('App about to enter foreground')
    if event.type == 262: # SDL_APP_DIDENTERFOREGROUND
        print('App entered foreground')
```

Not very elegant, but it works also on Pygame 2 built with buildozer.